# Unnecessary NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#

Why do I get a `NullReferenceException` in the following code?

```
private string FileR ( string name )
{
    string[] content = ReadSite(name, Protocol.read, url);
    Request_Template newCon;
    string[] final = new string[content.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
    {
        if (content[i].Equals(null))
        {
            return "content [" + i + "] returns null";
        }
        newCon = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Request_Template>(content[i]);

        if (newCon.Sender.Contains(myAccount.Username))
        {
            newCon.Sender = "Me";
        }

        string sender = newCon.Sender;
        string message = newCon.Message;
        final[i] = sender + ":\t" + message;
    }

    string nFinal = string.Concat(final);

    Thread.Sleep(10);
    return nFinal;
}

string[] ReadSite(string filename, Protocol p, string uri)
{
    Read_Template temp = new Read_Template
    {
        Chat = filename,
        Code = key1
    };
    string myUrl = JsonSerializer.Serialize(temp);

    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    Stream stream = web.OpenRead(uri + "/" + myUrl);

    int length = 0;
    while (new StreamReader(stream).ReadLine() != null)
    {
        length++;
    }
    string[] content = new string[length];

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            content[i] = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    return content;
}
```

I've tried using the debugging tools with no avail.  When I ran the code, it said that the error came from `string [] final = new string [content.Length];`
 and `for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)`.That lead me to assume that `content` was null. But when I used the watch window and it said that the variable `content` cannot be determined. How do I fix this?

Comment: put a breakpoint (F9) in the offending line and run again; could you receive an error from the remote address?

Comment: **Where** do you get a NullReferenceException?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the problem is actually here:

```cs
if (content[i].Equals(null))
```

If `content[i]` is genuinely null, then calling `content[i].Equals` will throw a `NullReferenceException`. That test should be written as:

```cs
if (content[i] is null)`
```

Or (for C# 6 or older):

```cs
if (content[i] == null)`
```

Now if `ReadSite` didn't have a bug in, you shouldn't need that check at all - because `ReadSite` should return an array of non-null string references. However, the way that you're populating the array is broken. You're currently:

- Creating a `StreamReader` around the stream
- Reading from the reader until you run out of data
- Creating a new array of the "right" length
- Creating another `StreamReader` around the same stream - which is by now at the end
- Reading from the reader however many times you read a line originally

Because the stream is already at the end, `ReadLine()` is going to return `null` on every iteration.

Instead, you should just read *once*, populating a list as you go, like this:

```cs
List<string> content = new List<string>();
using (var stream = web.OpenRead(uri + "/" + myUrl))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) is object)
        {
            content.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
return content;
```

That's returning a `List<string>`, so you'd want to change your `ReadSite` return type to `List<string>` or perhaps `IReadOnlyList<string>`. If you really need it to return an array, you could return `content.ToArray()` instead.

(Ideally, move to using `HttpClient` as well, but that's a different story.)

Comment: Good answer and I’m impressed by the time you took to explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
private string FileR ( string name )
{
    // ReadSite always returns a content that has length 0 or more. string[] content will never equals null. 
    // TEST: string[] test = new string[0]; test == null -> False
    string[] content = ReadSite(name, Protocol.read, url);
    Request_Template newCon;

    string[] final = new string[content.Length];

    // if content.Length == 0, this loop will never occur and you wont get any NREs.
    for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
    {
        // It is highly unlikely that a reader.ReadLine() would generate a null but 
        // just in case it does, use == null instead of .Equals() method. When content[i] == null, you cannot use .Equals() method since nulls dont have Equals method.
        if (content[i].Equals(null))
        {
            return "content [" + i + "] returns null";
        }

        // If you have checked that content[i] is Not empty space or null, you might 
        //end up with newCon == null if Deserialization fails. Cover this around try / catch.
        newCon = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Request_Template>(content[i]);

        // If deserialization fails, this will throw NRE because nulls wont have 
        // Sender as a property or array. Check if newCon == null or not. Also, 
        // check if Sender was correctly initialized as an array/list.. as it could 
        // be null. nulls wont have Contains as a method.
        if (newCon.Sender.Contains(myAccount.Username))
        {
            newCon.Sender = "Me";
        }

        string sender = newCon.Sender;
        string message = newCon.Message;

        // This should work correctly as its dependent on content.length. If the 
        // loop is happening, then there is at least one final element that can be updated.
        final[i] = sender + ":\t" + message;
    }

    string nFinal = string.Concat(final);

    Thread.Sleep(10);
    return nFinal;
}
```

Comment: "I dont believe you would get an error here" - what do you think `content[i].Equals(null)` will do if `content[i]` is null? Also suggesting the use of `string.IsNullOrEmpty` assumes the OP wants to do the same thing for "" as for null, which I don't think we have any indication of. (Note that `string.IsNullOrEmpty` would return false for `" "`, because a string that's got a space isn't empty.)

Comment: @JonSkeet (Console.ReadLine()) and would have \r or \n for blank lines, didnt think about the URL reader. Not sure still how reader.ReadLine() would create a null entry as an item of an array but if i hard code null as an element of array, == null works fine.  *I did update the above response accordingly*